# React select option sync with other react select option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

```
optionResultTask:[{label:"ApiTest1",value:"1111"},label:"ApiTest2",value:"2222"},{label:"ApiTest3",value:"3333"}]

<Select                                         
      options={optionResultTask}
      name="taskTitle1"
      onChange={this.handleTaskResultStatus}                                         
      value={resultTitle}                                        
      placeholder="Title"
      // isDisabled
     />

  <Select                                         
      options={optionResultTask}
      name="taskTitle2"
      onChange={this.handleTaskResultStatus}                                         
      value={resultTitle}                                        
      placeholder="Title"
      // isDisabled
     />
```

Hi, Im really new with React. So my question is How can **options** in "taskTitle1" and "taskTitle2" **sync**.

Example, if Selection in "taskTitle1" has been selected as (ApiTest1), then "taskTitle2" cannot be selected same as "taskTitle1", so the options should appear **ApiTest2** and **ApiTest3** only.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a filtered out array of options to both your Selects.

I noticed that both your Component are using the same value `resultTitle`. Since I think this is a typo I replaced their names with `resultTitle1` and `resultTitle2`

Code :

```
<Select                                         
    options ={optionResultTask.filter(option => option.value !== resultTitle2)}
    name="taskTitle1"
    onChange={this.handleTaskResultStatus}                                         
    value={resultTitle1}                                        
    placeholder="Title"
    // isDisabled
    />

<Select                                         
    options={optionResultTask.filter(option => option.value !== resultTitle1)}
    name="taskTitle2"
    onChange={this.handleTaskResultStatus}                                         
    value={resultTitle2}                                        
    placeholder="Title"
    // isDisabled
    />
```